# .NET MAUI project - Error when starting Android emulator

Tags: android, maui

I created a small project sample that works fine if I run it as a "Windows Machine" in VS2022

However, when I try to configure a new Android device emulator I get the following error:

"Intel HAXM is not installed. Please ensure your machine supports hardware virtualization, and install Intel HAXM using the SDK Manager."

I have enabled "Hyper-V" and "Windows Hypervisor Platform" from the "Turn Windows feature on or off"
and restarted my machine

from what I read since Windows supports Hyper-V there is no need to install intel HAXM directly (and from looking at their GitHub pages it seems deprecated)

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Android emulators can be interesting depending on your setup. There is a pretty good guide here available in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration).